# How to fix the jump destination error in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm building a simple program that is going to calculate the gals, miles and miles per gals depends on what the user inputs. What I am doing is creating a menu, and it will have 4 tasks. The user will enter a character assigned to each task. For example, if the user enters M, it will calculate the actual mpg. If s/he enters D, it will calculate the distance and so on. The program will loop back to the menu until the user types in Q. However, when I get to task 2, I got the compiler error, it says, jump destination too far....Now I did not know that there is a range for the jump condition. I use most the cmp and je instructions for the record. Here is my question, is there any way to fix that jump destination error ? and how would I do that ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
TITLE test.asm

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
menuString BYTE "M - Calculate the actual miles per Gallon or MPG", 0ah, 0dh
         BYTE "D - Calculate the max distance you can travel", 0ah, 0dh
         BYTE "G - Calculate the gas required for a trip", 0ah, 0dh
         BYTE "Q - Quit the program", 0ah, 0dh
         BYTE "Choose M, D, G, Q with the following option: ", 0

newLine BYTE "t ", 0ah, 0dh, 0

galsString BYTE "Gals: ", 0
milesString BYTE "Miles: ", 0
mpgString BYTE "MPG: ", 0

choice BYTE ?

gals DWORD ?
miles DWORD ?
mpg DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

Menu:
    mov edx, OFFSET menuString
    call WriteString                ; display the menu
    call ReadChar                   ; read the user input choice
    mov choice, al                  ; move the choice to AL register
    call WriteChar                  ; display the charater choice to screen
    cmp al, 4dh                 ; compare character choice to M = 4d in hex
    je M                        ; if equal, jump to M

    cmp al, 44h                 ; compare character choice to Q
    je D                        ; if equal, jump to D

    cmp al, 51h                 ; compare character choice to Q
    je Q                        ; if equal, jump to Q

    ;dividend ÷ divisor = quotient
    ;(eax) 32 bit

    M:
        mov edx, OFFSET newLine     ;
        mov edx, OFFSET milesString ; ask the user to input miles
        call WriteString        ; display miles to the screen

        call ReadDec            ; read the miles input and store to EAX register
        mov miles, eax          ; assign miles equal to EAX

        mov edx, OFFSET galsString  ; ask the user to input gals
        call WriteString        ; display gals to the screen

        mov edx , 0         ; set edx = 0, prepare for the divison

        call ReadDec            ; read the gals input and store to EAX register
        mov gals, eax           ; assign gals equal to EAX

        mov eax, miles          ; assign miles equal to EAX, make it a divident

        div gals            ; gals will be divisor  
        call WriteDec           ; write the result to screen
        loop Menu           ; go back to the menu

        D:
        mov edx, OFFSET mpgString
        call WriteString

        call ReadDec
        mov mpg, eax

        mov edx, OFFSET galsString
        call WriteString

        ;mov edx, 0

        call ReadDec
        mov gals, eax

        mov edx, mpg

        mul ecx
        call WriteDec
        loop Menu
    Q:
        exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 0):

If your assembler isn't clever enough to figure it out by itself, use explicit jump size override. This may look something like `je near`, `je near ptr` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

When using a relative jump there is a limit, so you can use the absolute jump like this:

```
mov eax,your_destination
jmp eax
```

For your example, you would need to use negative logic to skip the absolute jumps if the condition is not met. For example:

```
cmp al, 4dh                 ; compare character choice to M = 4d in hex
jne NOT_M
mov eax, M
jmp eax
NOT_M:

cmp al, 44h                 ; compare character choice to Q
jne NOT_D       
mov eax, D
jmp eax
NOT_D:

cmp al, 51h                 ; compare character choice to Q
jne NOT_Q      
mov eax, Q
jmp eax
NOT_Q:
```

Comment: if you're using the absolute jump, how are you going to check the condition to jump ? in my case, I have to check the input from the user to jump to a specific task.

Comment: There is only a size limit for the 8 bit form (`Jcc rel8`), the 32 bit form (`Jcc rel32`) can jump anywhere within the address space.

Comment: Ah, its a 32bit cpu? Didn't notice that :/

Comment: Surely you did ... how else could you be using `eax`?